Azure ACS Webhook for SMS Delivery Events Not Triggering Despite Logs
I've set up a toll-free number in Azure ACS and want to trigger an action when an SMS is either delivered or fails. To do this, I created a REST endpoint so Azure can send event details via webhook. I registered the webhook with Azure ACS events, and when I posted a sample payload manually, everything worked fine.
However, when I send an SMS using either the Azure portal or through my own code, the webhook is not triggered, even though I've done the following:

Enabled Microsoft.EventGrid
Registered the webhook with Azure ACS

I've also checked the Azure ACS logs and can see that the SMS event is logged correctly, but the call to the webhook is still not being made.
Has anyone else run into this issue or have any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

Please share the code you tried in text format and the document you referred to.

this is the document I referred : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/handle-sms-events
I need to understand why azure is not calling my webhook rest endpoint for SMS operations , but the same azure has successfully called my webhook while registering my endpoint.

A webhook is an HTTP endpoint that allows external applications to communicate with your system. You can implement webhooks using various Azure services, such as Azure Functions or a web app running an API.
I used the Azure Function EventGridTrigger to track the events of SMS received and SMS delivery reports.
Below is the C# Event Grid trigger code to track SMS events.
    [Function("HandleTelephonyAndSmsEvents")]
    public void Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Event received: {eventGridEvent.EventType}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"SMS Data: {eventGridEvent.Data}");
        if (eventGridEvent.EventType == "Microsoft.Communication.SMSReceived")
        {
           
            _logger.LogInformation($"SMS Received: {eventGridEvent.Data}");
        }
        else if (eventGridEvent.EventType == "Microsoft.Communication.SMSDeliveryReportReceived")
        {
          
            _logger.LogInformation($"SMS Delivery Report: {eventGridEvent.Data}");
        }
    }
}

Deploy the above Event Grid to Azure and use the URL as a webhook to track events. The URL will be in the following format:
https://ServiceName.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=Function1&code=eventgrid_extensionKey
I used this documentation to send SMS via the REST API by signing and making requests to Azure Communication Services' SMS API. The send event  are triggered to triggers as events.
Output:

In Azure Function:

